# Azure KeyVault 403 Forbidden when using Principal Account to access

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I created an `Azure KeyVault` that I want my `App Service` to be able to access. From what I can tell, the principal of my `App Service` should have access to the `KeyVault`, but I always get the following error when trying to retrieve from it. This happens whether I am running locally in `Visual Studio` or in `Azure`.

> Service request failed. Status: `403` (Forbidden) Content: {"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"The policy requires the caller 'appid=MY_APP_ID;oid=MY_PRINCIPAL_ID_STARTING_WITH_1A5 ;iss=https://sts.windows.net/REDACTED_GUID/' to use on-behalf-of (OBO) flow. For more information on OBO, please see [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2152310","innererror":{"code":"ForbiddenByPolicy"}}}](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2152310%22,%22innererror%22:%7B%22code%22:%22ForbiddenByPolicy%22%7D%7D%7D) Headers: Pragma: no-cache x-ms-keyvault-region: westus x-ms-client-request-id: REDACTED x-ms-request-id: REDACTED x-ms-keyvault-service-version: 1.2.236.0 x-ms-keyvault-network-info: conn_type=Ipv4;addr=52.155.40.204;act_addr_fam=InterNetwork; Strict-Transport-Security: REDACTED X-Content-Type-Options: REDACTED Content-Length: 387 Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Date: Wed, 21 Apr 2021 20:10:33 GMT Expires: -1 X-Powered-By: REDACTED

I have looked at the linked `KB` article and it talks about OAUTH`. I am not trying to use OAUTH, so I don't understand why that is relevant.

Here is the access policy in my `KeyVault`:

[image]

Here is the screenshot from the `App Service` where I configured a principal.

[image]

It clearly says at the bottom that it can be configured to access other resources, so I don't understand why it cannot access `KeyVault`.

Code used to attempt to access.

```
        var kvUri = "https://" + Properties.Settings.Default.KeyVaultName + ".vault.azure.net";
        var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
        var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri),credential );
        var result = client.GetSecret(secret);
```

Comment: What is the principal of your App Service? Is it an Azure Managed Identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set access policy, you need to select service principal with only object id (without app id).

See this similar post [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64215320/azure-how-to-fix-the-policy-requires-the-caller-to-use-on-behalf-of-obo?answertab=votes#tab-top).